# php perform javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, pdf

The following is the code I use in an Order Confirmation module. I am creating a pdf file using `fpdf` and also sending an email. Subsequently, I clear out a shopping cart and redisplay the menu.

In the code below, I have commented out the creation of the pdf file. When I do this  the email is sent and the cart is emptied by the javascript code

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
                doCart(\'EmptyCart\',\'0\', \'0\', \' \', \'partCheckOut\'); 
            </script>
```

but if I uncomment the code for the creation of the pdf:

```
            $pdf->getHdrDtl();
            $pdf->Header();
            $pdf->Footer();
            $pdf->generatePDF();
```

the pdf file is created, the email is sent, but the cart is not emptied and the menu is not redisplayed.

Does anyone have any suggestions or ideas?

```
if (isset($_POST['confirm']))
{ 
        $Cart->ConfirmOrder();
            /*
            $pdf->getHdrDtl();
            $pdf->Header();
            $pdf->Footer();
            $pdf->generatePDF();
             * 
             */
        $Cart->sendOrderEmails($dealer_email);
            echo '
            <script type="text/javascript">
                doCart(\'EmptyCart\',\'0\', \'0\', \' \', \'partCheckOut\'); 
            </script>
            ';
        $group = $_SESSION['group'];

        if ($group == 1){
                header("Refresh: 1; ./admin_menu.php");
                    exit;
        }
        if ($group == 2){
                header("Refresh: 1; ./user_menu.php");
                    exit;
        }
        if ($group == 3){
                header("Refresh: 1; ./admin_menu.php");
                    exit;
        }
}
```

Comment: Are you using some kind of javascript debugging tool to see if javascript errors are thrown?

Comment: I don't think you understand how the web works. PHP cannot execute JavaScript—it simply prints it and someone (possibly the browser) will execute it at a later stage. And you cannot send HTTP headers in the middle of your HTML.

Comment: PHP is a server-side language, javascript a client-side language, meaning the server send you an html page which javascript interact with.

Comment: I get that "you don't understand" stuff. The thing is why does it work in one case and not in another?

Comment: just to clarify why this problem is baffling me. There are 2 cases:

Comment: just to clarify why this problem is baffling me. These are the 2 lines where the problem lies: `$Cart->sendOrderEmails($dealer_email);
            echo '
            <script type="text/javascript">
                doCart(\'EmptyCart\',\'0\', \'0\', \' \', \'partCheckOut\'); 
            </script>
            ';` If they are preceded by `$Cart->ConfirmOrder()` they  are both executed and my cart is emptied. If they are preceded by the lines `...
            $pdf->generatePDF('Order.pdf','F');` the first line of the 2  is executed but the following line (echo ...) is not executed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your $pdf->generatePDF() is acting, but it looks like it generate the PDF inside the current page. The page is no more an HTML page but a PDF one. Consequently you can't write any javascript code into the page (or any html or text directly, you must use the FPDF functions to insert data into the PDF, and before the generation of the document).

And you definitely can't send any PHP header after sending data to the browser.
If you have to redirect after sending data, use javascript redirections.

Comment: good thought, but I am creating a pdf file on the system and also downloading a file via the browser. The browser remains at the screen I was in originally. These are the last lines of the code for `$pdf->generatePDF`: `        `$pdf->Output('Order.pdf','F'); 
        $pdf->Output('Order.pdf','D'); `